# Difference in testing for Enum Flags?

Tags: .net, enums

Was looking at another question, and was curious if there's any difference at all (in operation or performance) between these two.

Given:

```
[Flags]
enum TransportModes
{
   None = 0,
   Bus = 1,
   Train = 2,
   Plane = 4
}
```

And a variable

```
var trip = TransportModes.Bus | TransportModes.Train;
```

1. `if((trip & TransportModes.Bus) == TransportModes.Bus) ...`
2. `if((trip & TransportModes.Bus)) != 0) ...`

I know what they do bit wise, and I know that [HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) replaces them. But Jon Skeet recommends one, and the MSDN docs recommend another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second option will return true, if the values you gave your enum values are not powers of two. The first option doesn't have this problem.

Example:

```
[Flags]
enum TransportModes
{
   None = 0,
   Bus = 1,
   Train = 2,
   Plane = 5
}

var trip = TransportModes.Bus | TransportModes.Train;

if((trip & TransportModes.Plane) != 0)
    // will be executed
if((trip & TransportModes.Plane) == TransportModes.Plane)
    // won't be executed
```

Explanation:
`trip & TransportModes.Plane` is 1 which is apparently `!= 0`, but not equal to `TransportModes.Plane` which has a value of 5.

However, if you don't use powers of two for the values of a flag enum, you most likely have bigger issues. Think about what happens, if `Plane` would have the value 3: You couldn't tell `Bus | Train` and `Plane` apart...

Answer (score 2):

If `bus` is not a power of two (if it has multiple bits set), and `trip` has only some of those bits set, `(trip & bus) == bus` will be false, but `(trip & bus)) != 0` will be true.